# Preventing iPhone scaling when rotated

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

When I rotate my iPhone into landscape mode, the iPhone automatically bumps the text size up.

What is the best way to prevent this? I'd like rotation to give the visitor more text to read, not a larger font. Is JavaScript [like this](http://www.iphonemicrosites.com/articles/6-tips-to-optimize-your-current-site-for-the-iphone/) the only way to go?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use this CSS property

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Comment: Here you go
http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266